# No output when double clicking an item in QTreeWidget (PyQt)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtreewidget

I have created a window containing a QTreeWidget called StudentTreeWidget, and when double clicking on one of the items in the Tree Widget it should open up another window called StudentEnterprisePassport:

```
class Student_search(Ui_Student_search):
    def __init__(self, database, tableName, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.dbu = DB_manager_students.DatabaseUtility(database, tableName)
        self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)'), self.handleButton)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.UpdateTree()
        self.window4 = None

    def handleButton(self):
        if self.window4 is None:
            database = 'EnterprisePassport'
            tablename = 'students'
            self.window4 = StudentEnterprisePassport(database, tablename)
            self.window4.show()

class StudentEnterprisePassport(Ui_StudentEnterprisePassport):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.sessionTracker_btn.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
```

When running the code no error is outputted, however, nothing happens when I double click an item in the Tree Widget. The QTreeWidget window is being imported from a Ui file created and converted from Qt Designer.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import DB_manager_students, sys
(....)

class Ui_Student_search(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, database, tableName):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.dbu = DB_manager_students.DatabaseUtility(database, tableName)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.UpdateTree()

    def setupUi(self, Student_search):
        Student_search.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Student_search"))
        Student_search.resize(1299, 856)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Student_search)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
        self.StudentTreeWidget = QtGui.QTreeWidget(Student_search)
        self.StudentTreeWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("StudentTreeWidget"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.StudentTreeWidget)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

Code to input data into the TreeWidget:

```
def UpdateTree(self):
    col = self.dbu.GetColumns()
    table = self.dbu.GetTable()

    for c in range(len(col)):
        self.StudentTreeWidget.headerItem().setText(c, col[c][0])

    self.StudentTreeWidget.clear()

    for item in range(len(table)):
        QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.StudentTreeWidget)
        for value in range(len(table[item])):
            self.StudentTreeWidget.topLevelItem(item).setText(value, str(table[item][value]))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    db = 'EnterprisePassport'
    tableName = 'students'
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_Student_search(db, tableName)
    ex.show()
    x = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(x)
```

Comment: `self.window4 = StudentEnterprisePassport(database, tablename)`.........where is the code for `StudentEnterprisePassport`, you're also setting things up twice in the `__init__` methods of both classes you've posted

Comment: Sorry I didn't add it before. Updated the question now. I tried to work around the setting up of the classes, but I would always find myself receiving all sorts of errors, so this seemed to have worked for me. Does doing this affect the output of the code or the QTreeWidget double click item by any chance?

Comment: i can't say for sure as i don't have enough data to reproduce the behavior you're getting but if your file was generated from Qtdesigner you shouldn't have an `__init__` method in there....i'll post a temporary way for you to setup one of your classes

Comment: Which __init__ method are you referring to? The one from the generated file or the one from the main file?

Comment: The one from the generated file....did Qtdesinger add that for you?...don't think so

Comment: Yes you are right actually, it doesn't create one. What do you suggest that I do to possibly change this? Don't I need to create one for the Ui to set up and work? By default I only planned to use only the generated file to create the program, but I needed to connect my other windows together somehow eventually.

Comment: hmmm....i find that a bit strange...i've not worked with databases a lot in Qt but every single ui file i've generated only gives me a `setupUi` method which accepts a `QWidget` as the only argument

Comment: I created the __init__ myself, my apologies. But deleting it will cause several other issues in my main program.

Comment: see my answer, get rid of the `__init__` methods and fix your inheritance. you should be able to apply the same logic to `StudentEnterprisePassport`...if you have any issues don't hesitate to post :)

Comment: At SO it is recommended you edit the original question instead of asking the exact same question. This is a duplicate of the question that got plenty of suggestions that was never properly edited: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631562/no-output-when-double-clicking-an-item-in-qtreewidget